# Convert or format String with special characters

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I'm receiving some answers from an API and they are coming to me like this:

[image]

There's a way to handle with this since it is coming from the API? I've tried some encodingUtil methods, but I couldn't get the result I need.

Comment: What character encoding is used here? Do you have a way to find out?

Comment: Yes, they are "ã" and "ç"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, most likely the 3rd party system received input encoded in a way not directly translateable to UTF-8 and the third party system substituted the mis-encoded character using the UTF-8 � character [that means unrecognized](https://slangit.com/help/diamond_with_question_mark)

It is a perfectly legitimate UTF-8 character and without some lexical analysis to guess at what the character should be (typically, a character with a diacritical mark), you are stuck with it.

example - do a replace of all `servi�o` with `serviço`